# Ist "rauf voten" und "runter voten" eine akzeptable Übersetzung für "upvote" und "downvote"?

Tags: translation, verb

Was ist eine angemessene deutsche Übersetzung von *upvote* und *downvote*?

Das deutsche Verb *voten*  findet man  in  [Duden Online](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/voten).

Zur englischen Orthografie [siehe EL&U](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/20457/upvote-vs-up-vote-vs-up-vote).

Comment: Siehe auch https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/4973/how-do-you-say-i-1ed-you-in-german (Englisch)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ich würde für *aufwerten* und *abwerten* stimmen.

Verwendungsbeispiele:

> Sie mag die Antwort nicht, daher hat sie sie abgewertet.
>   Er hingegen fand Sie toll und hat sie mit seiner Stimme aufgwertet.

Comment: "aufwerten" klingt für mich allerdings nach einer Veränderung, also zum Beispiel einer Präzisierung der Frage. Analog zur "Aufwertung" eines Gebäues durch Modernisierung, etc.

Comment: @c089: Ja, und bei "Abwertung" denke ich an Inflation und Abwertung des Geldes.

Answer (score 6):

Wenn man “upvote” und “downvote” als Verben liest (to upvote, to downvote), dann sehe ich:

- auf- und abwerten (FUZxxls Vorschlag)
- wählen und abwählen
- zustimmen und widersprechen
- als gut/als schlecht markieren
- positiv/negativ bewerten
- loben/tadeln

Liest man sie als Substantive, (one upvote, one downvote), dann komme ich zu folgenden Vorschlägen:

- Stimme u. Gegenstimme
- Wahl u. Veto
- Plus- und Minuspunkt

Speziell für StackExchange würde ich empfehlen:

Hauptwörter:

```
 Die Frage bekam 4 Stimmen und 3 Gegenstimmen, 
 die Antwort 3 Pluspunkte und keinen Minuspunkt. 
 Die Metafrage erhielt 4x Zustimmung und 3x Ablehnung.
```

Verben:

```
 Stimm mit `^` zu und mit `v` dagegen. 
 Akzeptier diese Frage oder lehne sie ab. 

 Bewerte diese Antworten als gut und nicht als schlecht. :)
```

Answer (score 5):

Eine mögliche Variante, zdie zwar etwas lang ist, aber nicht zu gekünstelt wirkt:

- up vote: **Punkt vergeben**
- down vote: **Punkt abziehen**

Answer (score 4):

Neben dem Vorschlag im Titel sehe ich noch:

`hochstimmen, niederstimmen` als Möglichkeit an.

Erschwerend kommt hier hinzu, dass beide Möglichkeiten keine unmittelbare Hauptwortbildung zulassen. Gegenstimme gibt es ja noch, aber Zustimmung ist kein quantifizierbares Wort.

Answer (score 3):

Ich finde `"dafür stimmen"` und `"dagegen stimmen"` ganz passend als Übersetzung.