# Ist das Märchen aus uralten Zeiten oder einfach aus alten Zeiten?

Tags: reference, lyrics

Ich bin dabei Heines *Lorelei* auswendig zu lernen und es ist mir aufgefallen, dass es anscheinend kleine Variationen des Textes gibt.

Am üblichsten  scheint folgende Fassung zu sein:

> Ein Märchen aus alten Zeiten,
>   Das kommt mir nicht aus dem Sinn.

Aber man findet auch:

> Ein Märchen aus **uralten** Zeiten,
>   Das **geht** mir nicht aus dem Sinn.

und auch Zwischenversionen (uralten + kommt).

Ich möchte von euch erfahren:
Hat Heine wirklich mehrere Versionen geschrieben? Oder sind das Druckfehler? Gibt es eine "richtige, offizielle" Version?

Und, letztendlich, hieß diese verführerische junge Dame Lorelei oder Loreley oder Lore-Ley oder...?

Comment: sowohl i als auch y ist mögich: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Loreley

Comment: @splattne: in meiner Frage hatte ich geschrieben: "...dass es *scheinbar* kleine Variationen gibt..." und du hast das zu: "... dass es *anscheinend*  kleine Variationen gibt" korrigiert. Was ist der Unterschied?

Comment: @Georges *scheinbar* bedeutet "(nur) zum Schein", sprich: Es scheint so zu sein, *ist* aber nicht so. *Anscheinend* bedeutet "Es hat den Anschein / offenbar" – also im Sinne von "vermutlich", "alles deutet darauf hin". Diesen Fehler machen übrigens auch sehr viele Menschen, deren Muttersprache Deutsch ist.

Comment: Danke für die (wie üblich) klare Erklärung, @splattne. Es ist ein Trost, dass viele von euch Einheimischen den selben Fehler machen:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Die erste Strophe lautet im Original

> Ich weiß nicht was soll es bedeuten,
>   Daß ich so traurig bin;
>   Ein Märchen aus alten Zeiten,
>   Das kommt mir nicht aus dem Sinn.

Das Gedicht wurde im 19. Jahrhundert oft vertont. Das bekannteste Lied stammt von [Friedrich Silcher](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedrich_Silcher). Ich vermute, dass einige Textstellen geändert wurden, um die Metrik dem Rhythmus der Musik anzupassen:

> Ich weiß nicht, was soll es bedeuten
>   daß ich so traurig bin;
>   ein Märchen aus uralten Zeiten,
>   das kommt mir nicht aus dem Sinn.

Zur Schreibweise des Namens *Loreley*: Es existieren viele Varianten: Lorelei, Lore-Ley, Lurley, Lurelei, Lurlei. Auf Wikipedia beschäftigt sich ein Abschnitt mit dem [Ursprung des Namens](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loreley#Name), der nicht eindeutig geklärt ist.

Heinrich Heine wählte die Schreibweise *Lore-Ley* in seinem 1824 geschriebenen Gedicht.

---

Der Vergleich im [Google Ngram Viewer](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=M%C3%A4rchen%20aus%20alten%20Zeiten,M%C3%A4rchen%20aus%20uralten%20Zeiten&year_start=1824&year_end=2008&corpus=8&smoothing=3) könnte meine These (Gedicht/Lied) unterstützen:

[image: Heine Loreley Märchen aus alten uralten Zeiten]

Comment: [Hier](http://www.duesseldorf.de/heineinstitut/grafik/heine/lorel_ms.jpg) kann man einen Blick auf Heines Originalhandschrift werfen (leider ein wenig klein, aber man kann es gerade noch lesen).

Comment: Welche Quelle hast du für das Original, splattne?

Comment: @Takkat:darf ich dich bitten,  deinen Kommentar  in eine Antwort zu verwandeln? Er verdient es bestimmt.

Comment: @Georges in einem Buch nachgeschlagen; auch bei Wikipedia findet sich die "alte Zeiten"-Version; auch http://gutenberg.spiegel.de/buch/371/36 - Gegenfrage: Wo hast du "uralte Zeiten" gefunden?

Comment: Lieber splattne, die Version mit "uralten Zeiten" steht in einem französischen Lehrbuch:  *Assimil  Perfectionnement Allemand* von Volker Eisman [Das Buch ist, nebenbei gesagt, fantastisch: das beste, dass ich je gesehen habe, alle Sprachen zusammengenommen]

Comment: Aha, interessant. Ich vermute wirklich, dass das Lied etwas Verwirrung stiftet, da es sehr bekannt ist – vielleicht sogar bekannter als das ursprüngliche Gedicht.

Comment: Vielen Dank für die reiche Information und die Mühe, die du dir gegeben hast, splattne.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: Ich bin mir nicht so sicher, ob wir das Bildchen hier veröffentlichen dürfen und nur als Link darauf wäre es keine wirklich gute Antwort (meine ich).

Comment: @Takkat: OK, ich verstehe. Ich bin sicher, dass es  bald eine andere Gelegenheit geben wird, eine Antwort von dir abzustimmen (ist "abstimmen"  die richtige Übersetzung von "upvote"?). Danke nochmals.

Comment: @Georges Kennst du ein ähnliches Buch für die umgekehrte Richtung (Muttersprache Deutsch -> Lernsprache Französisch)? (Und *ab* ist wörtlich das Gegenteil von *up*, bedeutet mit "stimmen" aber nur "vote". Warum stellst du deine Kommentarfragen nicht lieber als echte Fragen? Scheinbar und abstimmen sind durchaus von allgemeinem Interesse.)

Comment: Lieber @Phira,  ja das ist ein guter Ratschlag: in der Zukunft werde ich meine Fragen als echte Fragen stellen, statt in den Kommentaren zu fragen. Und:  derselbe Verlag *Assimil"   hat zwei Bücher für Deutschsprachige die Französisch lernen wollen ; eins für Anfänger, das zweite für Fortgeschnitte.http://www.assimil.com/descriptionProduitDetail.do?paramIdProduit=1407&paramIdMethode=1407                                                                                                             http://www.assimil.com/descriptionProduitDetail.do?paramIdProduit=97&paramIdMethode=97

Comment: @Phira: Die Frage mit "upvote" wurde anscheinend schon aufgeworfen. Die vorgeschlagten Übersetzungen waren "aufwerten" und "hochstimmen". Gefallen sie dir?   http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/998/ist-rauf-voten-und-runter-voten-eine-akzeptable-ubersetzung-fur-upvote-und

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Es ist beides ok, aber wie so oft, ist die idiomatische Lösung eine Umformulierung zb "eine andere Gelegenheit geben wird, für eine Antwort von dir zu stimmen".

Comment: Es wäre hilfreich, die genaue Quelle der Antwort anzugeben. Dass es in einem Buch steht, ist bei einem editorischen Konflikt keine besonders hilfreiche Information. Es geht ja gerade darum, dass in verschiedenen Büchern verschiedene Versionen stehen.