# How do you say "I +1'ed you" in German?

Tags: english-to-german

How to say:

> I +1'ed you

in German in the context of SE sites where you upvote someone's post?

Comment: hmm - how would you **say** this in english? :)

Comment: @tohuwawohu: "I plus one'ed you" or something like that!

Comment: And what does it mean??? Hey, Joe, I've just one'ed you! And Lisa, I've five'ed you! Marcy, I've twentyseven'ed you! WOW, isn't that great?

Comment: Huh? it's normal to say "I plus one'ed you" in English. You can't plus one someone more than once, so  calm down.

Comment: Well, if its normal, then please tell me what it means. I never have heard this phrase before. I am a native german speaker. I can't translate it if I don't know what it means.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: It's the informal way of saying "I upvoted your post". It's everywhere in G+ and FB, I wonder how you have never heard of it.

Comment: @Gigili: I don't use Google+. In Facebook you can select the language, and there I did select my native language which is german. So the button for upvoting a post is not titled "I like" but "gefällt mir". But even if I would use the english version: I don't comprehend how "I like" would lead to a term like "i +1'ed you". Here in stackexchange I can upvote or downvote a post. Till now I thought you would say "I upvoted your post". I german this is: "I habe deinen Beitrag upgevoted". (you use "upvote" as an anglicism in a german context, so you applicate german grammar to an english word)

Comment: This would be very awkward because even +1 is not common in the United States outside of Silicon Valley. +1 is more likely to be used by users of Google+ which has low use anyways. So why not just use a better term like "I voted your post." Even here on SE few say `+1`, they say/write `upvoted`.

Comment: I added the answer `Ich upgevoted sie` but apparently was getting downvoted but no feedback. What would be wrong with using that?

Comment: @JGallardo It would be "Ich habe Sie upgevoted" or "Ich habe Sie geupvoted".

Comment: `man likt nicht, sondern "pluseinst"` https://www.zeit.de/digital/internet/2018-10/google-plus-soziales-netzwerk-datenleck-datenschutz-schliessung

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have also heard "Ich habe Dich/es geplust" (or for facebook: "Ich habe Dich/es geliked").

Personally I don't like Anglicisms but that's a life language for you...

Comment: *würg* Da dreht sich mir der Magen um. Bei beidem "Ich habe dich geplust" und "Ich habe dich geliked". Wenn du das das nächste hörst, gib dem jenigen links und rechts eins um die Ohren.

Comment: Tja, so ist das nunmal bei Sprachen, sie entwickeln sich durch die Leute, die sie verwenden. Ob es da was bringt, wenn man den Oberlehrer raushängen lässt, wage ich zu bezweifeln. Mich nerven diese Ausdrücke wesentlich weniger als die falsche Verwendung von "das" und "dass" oder ähnliches.

Comment: Immerhin gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen 'geplust' und 'geliked': 'geplust' ist das regelmäßig gebildete Partizip II eines Verbs 'plussen' (oder eher 'plusen', da würde man aber dazu neigen, das u lang auszusprechen), währen 'geliked' einfach nur Murks ist, weil das Partzip II im Deutschen nicht auf -d endet.

Comment: Daher, wenn schon, *gelik[e]t*.

Comment: "Liken" ist mittlerweile tatsächlich gebräuchlich.

Comment: "Geplust" war vor allem innerhalb von Google+ üblich. Da G+ vor ca. einem Jahr (2019-04-02) endgültig abgeschaltet wurde, ist es wohl aus der Mode gekommen. Aber die Frage bezog sich ja gerade auf das +1, was die Bezeichung innerhalb von Google+ war.

Answer (score 15):

There are different verbs to express consent / affirmation, but if you would say

> Ich stimme Dir zu.

or

> Ich pflichte Dir bei.

i wouldn't think of the SE upvote mechanism, but of a more general consent. Instead, i think most people would use a verb derived from "upvote" by just using it as a german verb, or by translating it partly:

> Ich habe Dich upgevotet / downgevotet.

or (with partial translation:

> Ich habe Dich hochgevotet / runtergevoted.

Written, those verbs look quite odd, but in spoken language, i think they're ok in that context. But i wouldn't use "upvoten" in other contexts, for example when talking about (political) elections or ballots.

Comment: Achtung! pedantic mode: You don't upvote people, but posts. It should not be "I +1'ed you" but "I +1'ed your post". So the best german translation is "Ich habe deinen Beitrag upgevoted".

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Nein. Kein einziges deutsches Partizip hört mit -ed auf. Wenn schon, dann "upgevotet"

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: "You don't upvote people, but posts." - that depends entirely on what the vote is supposed to express in the respective system.

Comment: Zur Referenz für die Partizipbildung: "updaten" und "upgraden" haben ihren Weg in den Duden gefunden, und die Partizipformen sind "upgedatet" und "upgegradet".

Answer (score 10):

Ich hab kein Problem mit +1, solange es nicht in ein Verb verwurstet wird.

Sag doch einfach "Ich habe für Deinen Beitrag gestimmt".

Answer (score 7):

Wer keinen Skrupel mit *»I +1'ed you«* im Englischen hat, sollte auch mit *»Ich +1'te dich«* im Deutschen keinen haben. Schließlich ist das Eine in der einen Sprache genauso gut oder schlecht wie das Andere in der anderen Sprache.

Sonst passiert nämlich das, was hier in einigen Kommentaren stattfindet: Man greift nach einem weniger anstößigen Anglizismus wie *upvote*, und in dem Versuch, diesen dann den Regeln der deutschen Grammatik zu unterwerfen, verzettelt man sich in Diskussionen darüber, ob es nun *upgevoted*, *geupvoted*, *upgevotet* oder *geupvotet* heißen müsste.

Alle anderen werden einfach den Reichtum der deutschen Sprache nutzen:

> - aufwerten – abwerten
> - hochstufen – (he)runterstufen

Comment: Naja Wortschöpfungen sollten zumindest aussprechbar sein. Ich kriege »Ich +1'te dich« nicht mal über die Zunge. Außerdem Verbbildung aus Nomen ist auf Englisch mehr oder weniger etabliert. Ich finde also dein Vergleich unpassend.

Comment: Verbbildungen aus Nomen sind auch im Deutschen üblich. Aber das ist hier eigentlich gar nicht Thema.

Comment: Aber nicht mal annähernd wie auf Englisch. In der Englischen Umgangsprache kannst du fast jeden beliebigen Nomen unverändert als Verb benutzen. Also warum ist das kein Thema? "+1" ist doch eine Substantivgruppe.

Comment: Na dann zitieren Sie doch mal ein paar Zeitungsartikel, Romane, etc. in denen die übliche “Substantivgruppe“ +1 oft verwendet wird. In meinem Dictionary steht sie nämlich nicht. Aber wie gesagt ... wir verzetteln uns in Diskussionen ... Hauptaussage meines Postings war eigentlich: nehmt deutsche Worte. Der Rest war motivierendes Beiwerk.

Comment: I am confused about what the scare quotes around "Substantivegruppe" are supposed to mean. I don't understand why you would expect to find one in a dictionary(so viel zum Thema "nehmt deutsche Worte") either.

Answer (score 6):

Im Geschäfft haben wir ein Code-Review-System, welches ein ähnliches Voting-Konzept hat. Fast jeder bei uns sagt:

> Ich habe dir plus 1 gegeben.

Für diesen Fall ist das Eins wesentlich, denn es gibt auch +2, -1 und -2. Ich denke jedoch die Anderen haben Recht, dass soetwas leicht komisch klingt.

Ich kann mich auch vage daran erinnern, als Google Plus (which also has the concept of giving +1) in weitere Verwendung war, haben sie es übersetzt als:

> diesen Beitrag +1 geben

Answer (score 2):

Etwas unhandlich, aber immerhin ohne Anglizismen und unmissverständlich. ;)

> Ich habe die Nützlichkeitswertung Deines Beitrags um eins inkrementiert.

Comment: Nützlichkeitswertung? Würdest *du* soetwas sagen? Inkrementieren, in dem Zusammenhang?

Comment: Nein, wohl nicht. Würde ich eventuell so sagen, um auch zum Ausdruck zu bringen, daß es dafür im Deutschen keinen ebenso griffigen Ausdruck gibt wie im Englischen, ich deswegen aber trotzdem ungern auf diesen ausweichen möchte. Wie wäre es mit "Ich habe Dir für den Beitrag ein plus eins gegeben."? Das wäre wohl eher praxistauglich.

Comment: Ja besser, das klingt natürlicher. Wobei ich nach wie vor kein Plus von "plus 1" bin, bestenfalls im Kontext mit Google+, sonst aber würde ich es vermeiden ;)

Comment: Gibt es übrigens ein Wort dafür, wenn man solche Sätze baut? Damit meine ich: wenn man den Verdacht hat, dass jemand sich an ein Synonymwörterbuch verschluckt hat.

Comment: Ganz ehrlich? Nein.

Answer (score 0):

To me, if someone plus ones you, it means "Me too." Or "I have this problem too (also)." So in German, I would say "Ich auch."

Comment: Als Kommentar, unter einem von Dir aufgewerteten Beitrag, würdest Du kommentieren "Ich auch"? Zum Beispiel unter dieser Frage? Das passt aber nicht!

Comment: The first answer mentioned a vote not the ES. I am thinking in terms of a help forum where someone has posted a problem. Someone else checks the forum for their problem and finds one that matches. So, they tic the box that says, I have this problem too. This lets developers know it is not happening to just one person.

Comment: So, in the sense of "plus another one" or "plus someone else".